# Selecting articles which is inside specific hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of article's categories which looks like this:

---

```
| Id | ParentId | Name
| 6  | 1        | Something else
| 5  | 2        | Mice
| 4  | 2        | Keyboards
| 2  | 1        | Computer accesories
| 1  | 0        | All
```

And as second table of articles:

```
| Id | CategoryId | Name
| 1  | 4          | Simple keyboard
| 2  | 5          | Simple mouse
| 3  | 6          | Simple nothing
```

Article.CategoryId -> Category.Id

Category.ParentId -> Category.Id

Now I need to select all articles that are computer accesories. How to do this? I have tried to do some recursive queries but didn't achieved anything working.

Expected result is:

```
| 1 | Simple keyboard
| 2 | Simple mouse
```

Since theirs categories points to a category that have parent category of ID 2 which am I searching for

Comment: "*I have tried to do some recursive queries*"... can you please post that? Also how the two tables are linked? what is the expected result

Comment: How many levels deep your hierarchy goes? It is relatively simple to query fixed levels (say up to 5 levels - can be done using JOINs); it takes more efforts to query unknown levels (needs recursive CTE or similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7bf81/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Category
(
  ID INT,
  ParentId INT,
  Name VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE Article
(
  ID INT,
  CategoryId INT,
  Name VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO Category 
VALUES
  (6,1, 'Something Else'),
  (5,2, 'Mice'),
  (4,2, 'Keyboards'),
  (2,1,'Computer Accessories'),
  (1, 0, 'All')


INSERT INTO Article
VALUES
  (1,4,'Simple keyboard'),
  (2,5,'Simple mouse'),
  (3,6,'Simple nothing')
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT ID, ParentId, Name
  FROM Category
  WHERE Name = 'Computer Accessories'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT c1.ID, c1.ParentId, c1.Name
  FROM Category c1
  INNER JOIN CTE c2
    ON c1.ParentId = c2.Id
)
SELECT Article.Id, Article.Name
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN Article
  ON Article.CategoryId = CTE.Id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7bf81/1/0)**:

```
| ID |            NAME |
|----|-----------------|
|  1 | Simple keyboard |
|  2 |    Simple mouse |
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT * FROM
Categories C
LEFT JOIN
Articles A
ON C.Id = A.CategoryId
WHERE C.Name = "Computer Accessories"
```

This will select "Computer Accessories" as a name - this has an ID assigned to it, which is 2. Through the join it will show you all articles that have category ID 2.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need. I need articles that have category which is a child of another category (with ID 2)